# how to secure sqflite database Flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

I wonder if sqflite package in flutter is secure and hidden in the devices?

I could see sqflite database in my ios device in path:
Files -> Browse -> Locations section -> On my iPhone -> AppName -> db_name.db

I found the database I created in the path above, and I think every one can edit, it's a big problem. So how to hide/encrypt the database in devices?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can usethis package

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_sqlcipher

And set a password to accessthe db content

```
import 'package:sqflite_sqlcipher/sqflite.dart';

Database db = await openDatabase(
  path,
  password: "my password",
  // onCreate, onUpgrade...
);
```

Comment: But sqflite_sqlcipher package is new and the publisher is unverified and may not be updated in the future. I need to Hide the database in the device not only set a password.

Comment: I dont think its possible to hide it. You can only encrypt it or make it hard to access

Comment: I tried sqflite_sqlcipher and it has been conflict because the app has already created a database with sqflite package. So sqflite_sqlcipher not just add password, it's not same as sqflite. sqflite_sqlcipher is not a good solution because the app will have conflict when users update to a new version which contain sqflite_sqlcipher.